# taglib-sharp id3v2 wrong character encoding

Tags: encoding, taglib-sharp

I've got an mp3 with cyrillic text in both v1 and v2 tags. Windows and media players (aimp) display both tags fine. However when I parse tags using `taglib-sharp` (also tried a few similar libs) i'm getting weird characters like `Äåðæèñü`. I know there can be an issue with specific files but as Windows and players are OK then there must be a way to properly decode it. How can I decode that?

Comment: In which tag or frame exactly do you get this 'weird characters'?

Comment: For example `Title` and `Artist`.

Comment: You can try with one of the UTF types (like UTF8 or UTF16...). Details see https://github.com/mono/taglib-sharp/blob/master/src/TagLib/ByteVector.cs

Comment: I'm having a similar problem with this too, but it's for extracting HEX values... Anyway, here is the correct URL: https://github.com/mono/taglib-sharp/blob/master/src/TaglibSharp/ByteVector.cs